# .htaccess 404 different errorpages

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a multilanguage site with `example.com/en/` and `/fr/`, `/de/` and so on.

now i wanted to have a default errorpage, e.g. in `example.com/en/404.php` (in all language directories)

If someone calls `example.com/de/site-not-existing` i want show `example.com/de/404.php`. this should also be available for `/en/` and `/fr/`

my problem is that i cannot use `ErrorDocument` in my .htaccess, because it's only possible to set one ErrorDocument.

is there another solution? i thought about creating a htaccess in each language directory, but it would be better, if i can set all from the one in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mod_rewrite` rules for this in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/ /$1/404.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have all your 404 go to a 404.php, and then utilizing $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], you can detect which language variant the user came from that landed them to the 404 page, and redirect them to the appropriate 404.php